# all white text in vscode?

Tags: php, html, visual-studio-code

I am starting learning Php, I have all my setup and so on, the only issue is, all the text is in white, I had my Prettier extension before, still works fine with other languages just not working with PHP.
as you can see in this picture, this is how  my setting.json file looks like

[image: picture]

```
{
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "workbench.statusBar.visible": true,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
  "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
  "java.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
  "java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home",
  "java.help.firstView": "gettingStarted",
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "typescript.format.insertSpaceAfterTypeAssertion": true,
  "typescript.format.placeOpenBraceOnNewLineForFunctions": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",

  "html.format.endWithNewline": true,
  "javascript.format.insertSpaceAfterConstructor": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "atlascode.bitbucket.enabled": false,
  "files.associations": {
    "*.js": "javascriptreact",
    "*.php": "php"
  },
  "angular.experimental-ivy": true,
  "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
  "workbench.editorAssociations": {
    "*.ipynb": "jupyter.notebook.ipynb"
  },
  "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "beautify.config": "",
  "beautify.language": {
    "js": {
      "type": ["javascript", "json", "jsonc"],
      "filename": [".jshintrc", ".jsbeautifyrc"]
    },
    "css": ["css", "less", "scss"],
    "html": ["htm", "html", "php", "blade"]
  },
  "phpformatter.additionalExtensions": [],
  "phpfmt.exclude": [],
  "phpfmt.passes": [],
  "html.format.templating": true,
  "intelephense.phpdoc.classTemplate": {
    "summary": "$1",
    "tags": ["@package ${1:$SYMBOL_NAMESPACE}"]
  },
  "[php]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
  },
  "phpformatter.arguments": ["--level=psr2"],
"phpfmt.cakephp": true
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the extension **PHP Extension Pack** and **PHP IntelliSense**, also if you like to check for bug you will need to set you path to your php.exe in your setting.json
example

```
    "php.validate.executablePath": "c:/xampp/php/php.exe",
```