# PHP file, the HTML text color in vsCode is white

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Why is my php file not highlighting the html code? It was working but it now the text are all white. I tried a few tricks like reinstalling prettier and trying to remove conflicting plugins.

I tried referencing this issue but no luck: [all white text in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68990975/all-white-text-in-vscode)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

install the extension PHP Extension Pack and PHP IntelliSense

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).